# How to practically make a bridge between user interface and the RFID reader/KOHA database? in java

Tags: java, database

I am stuck in Koha database and RFID reader?  How to make a bridge between Koha database and RFID reader in Java.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This requires 2 steps.
1. Authenticate as Library Admin
2. Access the "Circulation" modules via REST, but looks like this is not easy. The only link I found so far was :
[ILSDL interface](http://koha.adminkuhn.ch/cgi-bin/koha/ilsdi.pl)